# Best way to implement Enums with Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

What is the best way to bind Core Data entities to enum values so that I am able to assign a type property to the entity? In other words, I have an entity called `Item` with an `itemType` property that I want to be bound to an enum, what is the best way of going about this.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You'll have to create custom accessors if you want to restrict the values to an enum. So, first you'd declare an enum, like so:

```
typedef enum {
    kPaymentFrequencyOneOff = 0,
    kPaymentFrequencyYearly = 1,
    kPaymentFrequencyMonthly = 2,
    kPaymentFrequencyWeekly = 3
} PaymentFrequency;
```

Then, declare getters and setters for your property. It's a bad idea to override the existing ones, since the standard accessors expect an NSNumber object rather than a scalar type, and you'll run into trouble if anything in the bindings or KVO systems try and access your value.

```
- (PaymentFrequency)itemTypeRaw {
    return (PaymentFrequency)[[self itemType] intValue];
}

- (void)setItemTypeRaw:(PaymentFrequency)type {
    [self setItemType:[NSNumber numberWithInt:type]];
}
```

Finally, you should implement `+ keyPathsForValuesAffecting<Key>` so you get KVO notifications for itemTypeRaw when itemType changes.

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingItemTypeRaw {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"itemType"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you — too bad Core Data doesn't support this natively. I mean: Xcode generates class files, why not `enum`s?

Comment: The last code is if you want to observe item itemTypeRaw. However, you can simply observe item itemType instead of itemTypeRaw right?

Comment: With Xcode 4.5 you don't need any of this. Take a look at my answer. You just need to define the enum as an `int16_t` and you're set.

Answer (score 80):

You can do this way, way simpler:

```
typedef enum Types_e : int16_t {
    TypeA = 0,
    TypeB = 1,
} Types_t;

@property (nonatomic) Types_t itemType;
```

And in your model, set `itemType` to be a 16 bit number. All done. No additional code needed. Just put in your usual

```
@dynamic itemType;
```

If you're using Xcode to create your `NSManagedObject` subclass, make sure that the "*use scalar properties for primitive data types*" setting is checked.

Comment: Are there any limits with which iOS / OS X versions this will work with?

Comment: It’s been working for as long as I remember, but I can't make any promises. I remember using this on iOS 5, but I don't know why it wouldn't work with iOS 4...

Comment: Note, this is a C++11 feature called "enum classes". http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with C++11. It's part of clang 3.3 supporting **Enumerations with a fixed underlying type** for ObjC. C.f. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objective-c-features

Comment: How do you avoid losing this code every time you regenerate the model class? I have been using Categories so that the core domain entities can be regenerated.

Comment: Since this doesn't have the `retain` keyword, will it still get stored in the database?

Comment: The `retain` is related to memory management, **not** whether it gets stored into the database or not.

Comment: I agree with Rob. I don't want this to have to be regenerated over and over again. I prefer the category.

Comment: Sure looks like C++ with all the underscores

Comment: @Rob To avoid the enum being overwritten every time the model class is regenerated, I wrote my typedef in a separate .h header file. So only two things need changing when the file is regenerated, the property type to the enum and re-including the header file with the enum. Not perfect, but the best I could come up with if following this pattern.

Comment: @Rob Categories is a way to do it, but instead you could also use mogenerator: https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator. Mogenerator will generate 2 classes per entity, where one class will always be overwritten on data model changes and the other subclasses that class for custom stuff and never gets overwritten.

Comment: I'm getting a bad access with this

Comment: How can you do this in Swift? If I am correct then this "trick" is not reproducible in Swift. See as well my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656219/best-way-to-implement-enums-with-core-data-in-swift/27694945#27694945

Comment: Swift `enum` is something very, very different from a C / ObjC enum. I'm not sure if there's any good way to fudge it…

Comment: I have been using this in my code but this throws me errors every time: CoreData: error: Property <> is a scalar type on class <> that does not match its Entity's property's scalar type.  Dynamically generated accessors do not support implicit type coercion.  Cannot generate a setter method for it. I just want to use the accepted answer after trying so much.

Comment: @Daniel Eggert , i try to use this but i am getting an error,  Declaration of 'int16_t" must be imported from module . Can you help me on that. Many thanks in advance

Comment: In ObjC `int16_t` is already defined if you import Foundation or CoreData. Are you using Swift? You need to make sure that your scalar type in the entity definition matches the `int16_t` -> 16 bit.

Comment: I was using this technique until I discovered a major problem that doing it this way prevents changedValues from containing the key.

Comment: @p0lAris I've been having the same error , because i thought i was doing the same implementation, but there's one thing you and I didn't notice at first. "typedef enum Types_e : int16_t {" this line, you probably have something like that instead "typedef enum {"

Comment: Any chance you could edit Types_e and Types_t to something clearer? thanks

Comment: If you're getting BAD_ACCESS errors or similar, be sure that the proper type (*i.e.* `int16_t`) is set in your model file. If you're using Xcode to create your `NSManagedObject` subclass, make sure that the "*use scalar properties for primitive data types*" setting is checked.

Comment: @malhal is right! this seems to mess up CoreData change notifications

Answer (score 22):

An alternative approach I'm considering is not to declare an enum at all, but to instead declare the values as category methods on NSNumber.

Comment: Interesting. It definitely seems doable.

Comment: brilliant idea!  so much easier than creating tables in the db, unless your db is filled from a web service then its probably best to use a db table!

Comment: Here's an example: http://renovatioboy.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/super-useful-nsnumberenum-category/

Comment: I like it. I'm going to use this approach in my project. I like that I can also contain all my other meta information about the meta data within the NSNumber category. (i.e. linking strings to the enum values)

Comment: Really great idea! Very useful for associating string identifiers, using directly in JSON, Core Data, etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using mogenerator, have a look at this: https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator/wiki/Using-enums-as-types. You can have an Integer 16 attribute called `itemType`, with a `attributeValueScalarType` value of `Item` in the user info. Then, in the user info for your entity, set `additionalHeaderFileName` to the name of the header that the `Item` enum is defined in. When generating your header files, mogenerator will automatically make the property have the `Item` type.

Answer (score 2):

I set the attribute type as 16 bit integer then use this:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

enum {
    LDDirtyTypeRecord = 0,
    LDDirtyTypeAttachment
};
typedef int16_t LDDirtyType;

enum {
    LDDirtyActionInsert = 0,
    LDDirtyActionDelete
};
typedef int16_t LDDirtyAction;


@interface LDDirty : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* identifier;
@property (nonatomic) LDDirtyType type;
@property (nonatomic) LDDirtyAction action;

@end
```

...

```
#import "LDDirty.h"

@implementation LDDirty

@dynamic identifier;
@dynamic type;
@dynamic action;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since enums are backed by a standard short you could also not use the NSNumber wrapper and set the property directly as a scalar value. Make sure to set the data type in the core data model as "Integer 32".

MyEntity.h

```
typedef enum {
kEnumThing, /* 0 is implied */
kEnumWidget, /* 1 is implied */
} MyThingAMaBobs;

@interface myEntity : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic) int32_t coreDataEnumStorage;
```

Elsewhere in code

```
myEntityInstance.coreDataEnumStorage = kEnumThing;
```

Or parsing from a JSON string or loading from a file

```
myEntityInstance.coreDataEnumStorage = [myStringOfAnInteger intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this a lot and find the following form to be useful:

```
// accountType
public var account:AccountType {
    get {
        willAccessValueForKey(Field.Account.rawValue)
        defer { didAccessValueForKey(Field.Account.rawValue) }
        return primitiveAccountType.flatMap { AccountType(rawValue: $0) } ?? .New }
    set {
        willChangeValueForKey(Field.Account.rawValue)
        defer { didChangeValueForKey(Field.Account.rawValue) }
        primitiveAccountType = newValue.rawValue }}
@NSManaged private var primitiveAccountType: String?
```

In this case, the enum is pretty simple:

```
public enum AccountType: String {
    case New = "new"
    case Registered = "full"
}
```

and call it pedantic, but I use enums for field names, like this:

```
public enum Field:String {

    case Account = "account"
}
```

Since this can get laborious for complex data models, I wrote a code generator that consumes the MOM / entities to spit out all the mappings.  My inputs end up being a dictionary from Table/Row to Enum type.  While I was at it, I also generated JSON serialization code.  I've done this for very complex models and it has turned out to be a big time saver.

Answer (score 0):

The code pasted below works for me, and I've added it as full working example. I'd like to hear opinions on this approach, as I plan to used it extensively throughout my apps.

- I've left the @dynamic in place, as it is then satisfied by the getter/setter named in the property.
- As per the answer by iKenndac, I have not overridden the default getter/setter names.
- I've included some range checking via a NSAssert on the typedef valid values.
- I've also added a method to obtain a string value for the given typedef.
- I prefix constants with "c" rather than "k". I know the reasoning behind "k" (math origins, historical), but it feels like I am reading ESL code with it, so I use "c". Just a personal thing.

There is a similar question here: [typedef as a Core data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448475/typedef-as-a-core-data-type)

I'd appreciate any input on this approach.

```
Word.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

typedef enum {
    cPresent            = 0,    
    cFuturProche        = 1,    
    cPasseCompose       = 2,    
    cImparfait          = 3,    
    cFuturSimple        = 4,    
    cImperatif          = 5     
} TenseTypeEnum;

@class Word;
@interface Word : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * word;
@property (nonatomic, getter = tenseRaw, setter = setTenseRaw:) TenseTypeEnum tense;

// custom getter & setter methods
-(void)setTenseRaw:(TenseTypeEnum)newValue;
-(TenseTypeEnum)tenseRaw;
- (NSString *)textForTenseType:(TenseTypeEnum)tenseType;

@end


Word.m


#import "Word.h"

@implementation Word

@dynamic word;
@dynamic tense;

// custom getter & setter methods
-(void)setTenseRaw:(TenseTypeEnum)newValue
{
    NSNumber *numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:newValue];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"tense"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:numberValue forKey:@"tense"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"tense"];
}


-(TenseTypeEnum)tenseRaw
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"tense"];
    NSNumber *numberValue = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"tense"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"tense"];
    int intValue = [numberValue intValue];

    NSAssert(intValue >= 0 && intValue <= 5, @"unsupported tense type");
    return (TenseTypeEnum) intValue;
}


- (NSString *)textForTenseType:(TenseTypeEnum)tenseType
{
    NSString *tenseText = [[NSString alloc] init];

    switch(tenseType){
        case cPresent:
            tenseText = @"présent";
            break;
        case cFuturProche:
            tenseText = @"futur proche";
            break;
        case cPasseCompose:
            tenseText = @"passé composé";
            break;
        case cImparfait:
            tenseText = @"imparfait";
            break;
        case cFuturSimple:
            tenseText = @"futur simple";
            break;
        case cImperatif:
            tenseText = @"impératif";
            break;
    }
    return tenseText;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution for Auto Generated Classes

#### from Xcode's Code Generator (ios 10 and above)

If you create an Entity named "YourClass", Xcode automatically will choose "Class Definition" as default a Codegen type at "Data Model Inspector". this will generate classes below:

#### Swift version:

```
// YourClass+CoreDataClass.swift
  @objc(YourClass)
  public class YourClass: NSManagedObject {
  }
```

#### Objective-C version:

```
// YourClass+CoreDataClass.h
  @interface YourClass : NSManagedObject
  @end

  #import "YourClass+CoreDataProperties.h"

  // YourClass+CoreDataClass.m
  #import "YourClass+CoreDataClass.h"
  @implementation YourClass
  @end
```

We'll choose "Category/Extension" from Codegen option instead of "Class Definition" in Xcode.

Now, If we want to add an enum, go and create another extension for your auto-generated class, and add your enum definitions here like below:

```
// YourClass+Extension.h

#import "YourClass+CoreDataClass.h" // That was the trick for me!

@interface YourClass (Extension)

@end


// YourClass+Extension.m

#import "YourClass+Extension.h"

@implementation YourClass (Extension)

typedef NS_ENUM(int16_t, YourEnumType) {
    YourEnumTypeStarted,
    YourEnumTypeDone,
    YourEnumTypePaused,
    YourEnumTypeInternetConnectionError,
    YourEnumTypeFailed
};

@end
```

Now, you can create custom accessors if you want to restrict the values to an enum. [Please check the accepted answer by question owner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1624352/4145420). Or you can convert your enums while you set them with explicitly conversion method using the cast operator like below:

```
model.yourEnumProperty = (int16_t)YourEnumTypeStarted;
```

[Also check](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html)

#### Xcode automatic subclass generation

> Xcode now supports automatic generation of NSManagedObject subclasses
>   in the modeling tool. In the entity inspector:
>
> Manual/None is the default, and previous behavior; in this case, you
>   should implement your own subclass or use NSManagedObject.
>   Category/Extension generates a class extension in a file named like
>   ClassName+CoreDataGeneratedProperties. You need to declare/implement
>   the main class (if in Obj-C, via a header the extension can import
>   named ClassName.h). Class Definition generates subclass files named
>   like ClassName+CoreDataClass as well as the files generated for
>   Category/Extension. The generated files are placed in DerivedData and
>   rebuilt on the first build after the model is saved. They are also
>   indexed by Xcode, so command-clicking on references and fast-opening
>   by filename works.