# How to store a typedef enum in CoreData

Tags: cocoa, core-data, enums

I have a typedef enum I use to represent a state of a job in a queueing system and it is defined as

```
typedef enum  {
kTWjobStateRunning,
kTWjobStateQueued,
kTWjobStateError
}TWjobState;
```

Everything is fine, but now I would like to store it as an attribute in CoreData. My first idea is that an enum is basically an integer, so would wrapping the `TWjobState` in a `NSNumber` work? Do I have to use casts to persuade the compiler?

**Best practice question**
I saw this use of enums often in Cocoa and Foundation classes and also the use of bitmasks. Is there a more modern, more object-oriented way to achieve the same?

*Thanks for your help.*

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624297/best-way-to-implement-enums-with-core-data) contains more elaborate answer to the same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Storing enums in an `NSNumber` is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Although it will require updating if you modify the `enum` and assuming you use sequential values in the enum, you can use CoreData's validation system to set upper and lower bounds corresponding to the max/min enum values.