# How to convert typedef enum to NSNumber?

Tags: enums, typedef, nsnumber, nsinteger, nsuinteger

1. Is each value of a `typedef enum` treated as an `int`?

   E.g., given the following `typedef enum`:

   ```
   // UIView.h

   typedef enum {
       UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut,
       UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn,
       UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut,
       UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
   } UIViewAnimationCurve;
   ```

   How do I know which method to use to create an `NSNumber`?

   ```
   + (NSNumber *)numberWithShort:(short)value;
   + (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedShort:(unsigned short)value;
   + (NSNumber *)numberWithInt:(int)value;
   + (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)value;
   + (NSNumber *)numberWithLong:(long)value;
   + (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedLong:(unsigned long)value;
   + (NSNumber *)numberWithLongLong:(long long)value;
   + (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedLongLong:(unsigned long long)value;
   + (NSNumber *)numberWithInteger:(NSInteger)value NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
   + (NSNumber *)numberWithUnsignedInteger:(NSUInteger)value NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
   ```

   I think `+[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` is the correct method to use because the [accepted answer to Best way to implement Enums with Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1624352/242933) uses it. E.g.:

   ```
   [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear]
   ```

   But, if `+[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` is correct, then why?
2. For a bitwise `enum`, e.g.:

   ```
   enum {
       UIViewAutoresizingNone                 = 0,
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = 1 << 0,
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = 1 << 1,
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  = 1 << 2,
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    = 1 << 3,
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       = 1 << 4,
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin = 1 << 5
   };
   typedef NSUInteger UIViewAutoresizing;
   ```

   I'm guessing that `+[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:]` is the correct method to use because there is an explicit `NSUInteger` after `typedef`. Correct? E.g.:

   ```
   [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:UIViewAutoresizingNone]
   ```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nowadays modern syntax can be used:

`@(UIViewAnimationCurveLinear)`

Answer (score 8):

[NSNumber numberWithInt:your_enum_int_variable];

Comment: You rock!
Thank for this.