# Core Data: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when using plain int data type

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have some doubts regarding storing plain "int" or "short" (int16_t) attributes inside the "Core Data" data management framework (on iOS 6 in my case). 
I tried using it various ways and found it impossible to do, failing with the above mentioned exception. Now, a few weeks later, I found this article inside StackOverflow and it looks like someone does exactly that:

See following example for storing an Enumeration in the lower answer from "Daniel Eggert":
[Best way to implement Enums with Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624297/best-way-to-implement-enums-with-core-data)

Here it looks as if he uses a plain "int16_t" and maps it to a "Core Data" entry "Integer 16" inside the data model... does this really work? I tried it exactly as stated (even using the same naming :-)) and it fails with the well known "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" exception... as expected.

Any thoughts on this one? Did I misinterpret the linked answer?

---- Edit: ---
Interesting how someone rates this question (that even properly links another question) down, but doesn't have an answer?! Anyway:

I now tried the very same with the "Event" sample application from Apple and it works.
My own test doesn't work, still. Main difference between the apps:

- My managed class is not auto-generated, I reused an existing class
- I still have some properties with "@synthesize" in my existing class

My own entity (managed object):
h:

```
@interface TestEntity : NSManagedObject
{
}
@property (nonatomic) int64_t testAttribute;
@end
```

m:

```
@dynamic testAttribute;
```

model data type: "Integer 64".

other.m:

```
TestEntity *testEntity = (TestEntity *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Trip" inManagedObjectContext:[GenericDAO getManagedContext]];
[testEntity setTestAttribute : 4]; //this triggers the exception
```

Comment: Can you post your code? I've used the code in the link without problem

Comment: That answer looks fine, if it's not working for you then post some code so we can see how you implemented it.

Comment: is that the auto generated code? I am guessing the real object is expecting an NSNumber...

Comment: Indeed, if I use NSNumber, then it works. Nevertheless when I use the original sample app delivered with the Apple documentation, I can make such a property work... and also the linked article indicates this should work. I guess there is a tiny glitch that is not so obvious :).

Comment: I didn't say that your code should work, I said that the code in that other answer works. I don't know exactly what's different yet. Do you get any compiler warnings for the line that triggers the exception? I'm also suspicious of "I reused an existing class". I'm guessing your existing class doesn't match your entity somehow.

Comment: I checked my warnings for the project and there are none. One thing I tested just now is this: when deliberately renaming the model-attribute (in the model definition), THEN I get a runtime exception telling me the selector is unrecognized. Which tells me that the model<->entity mapping is somehow functional for this property. Regarding your question Tom: the other properties I use (such as NSString's and NSNumber's) work fine in the very same entity.

Comment: What's the minimum version of iOS you're supporting with this code?

Comment: everything in core data should be object. i.e. `NSNumber` for integer type

Comment: @xlc true but the accessor methods can take primitive ints, depending on the version of iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going into detail with the whole issue the last week, I found out that using iOS 6 and the latest XCode (4.6.2 in my case) I can do everything exactly as specified in the link mentioned in my question. The issues I have seen are related to a set of technical details that are simply not documented. How did I find out about it? I simply did the following steps to validate my entities:

- Create a new empty project with Xcode that support Core Data
- Use the "editor" menu item "import" when being in Xcode, having the data model open (select the "XY.xcdatamodeld" you want to use with Core-Data.
- You will see which items are imported in your model and which are "incorrectly" specified (either by property settings or else)
- Now simply create all attributes you originally wanted to have coded as primitive data types, and select the "export" menu item inside the "editor" menu (when data model is selected!). Careful: check the "create primitive data type" check box to get base-types instead of Cocoa/object properties.

To check back your original project, do this also in the original project, in my case Core-Data and even the menu items looked differently (some options are greyed-out):

- Do the same steps (importing entities into the data model) in old/your *current* project.
- If the result is different, this will tell you that your *project* settings are somehow incompatible/old and you can go change the project settings to find out which ones impact the Core Data behavior.
- Also try to use the export function to see if it generates the code correctly.

Other important tip: you can select the attributes in the Core-Data data-model editor and copy/paste them between projects.. This comes very handy if you want to migrate some entities/properties for testing. Do not just copy over the whole "cxdatamodeld" settings file, it keeps its settings from the old project (I tried it two times to validate that).

Answer (score 0):

Check you set the Name, Class and Parent Entity correctly for all the entities in your Core Data Model file. Check all your class names match your entity names. The reason for the problem is when compiling the model it doesn't find the header file with the setter.