# Adding the Results of a UISegmentedControl to an Attribute in a Core Data Entity

Tags: ios, core-data, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am progressing nicely within my basic first application; I am fairly new to App development but have been working on it for quite some time. I have tried to find an answer to this question that just didn't make sense to me.

I have a single `UITableViewController` which has a plus button that points to a `ModalViewController`; this asks the user to fill in 3 fields with text and select "Bought or Sold" which I've set up as a `UISegmentedController` in the UI with the first button saying "Bought" and the second saying "Sold".

My class for adding the values of the three text fields contains the following code and when I click Save, it returns to the `UITableView` and displays the typed content.

I would like to set the cell of be one color for Bought and one color for Sold. I can do that easily enough with the cellForRow, etc. The problem is the data model and the code which I need help with.

I have a data model with the following Entities:

- Transaction, Person, Occasion and Amount

Transaction has a relationship to Person, Occasion and Amount. It also has a "status" attribute which is the result of the `UISegmentedControl`.

What type do I set this to be is my first question? BOOL?

Next, what kind of code can/should I use to get that value from the user and add it to the database?

This is the current save method for the textFields:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *transaction = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Transaction" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *person = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *occasionEvent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Occasion" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSManagedObject *amountType = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Gift" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [person setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [occasionEvent setValue:self.occasionTextField.text forKey:@"title"];
    [amountType setValue:self.amountTextField.text forKey:@"amount"]; 
    [transaction setValue:person forKey:@"whoBy"];
    [transaction setValue:occasionEvent forKey:@"occasion"];
    [transaction setValue:amountType forKey:@"gifting"];    
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Can't save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);

    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];   
}
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What type do I set this to be is my first question? BOOL?

If there're only two options you may use a Boolean value. If you do that I advise to change its name to something more telling than `status`, for example `wasBought`. In my opinion it'd be even better to use enum, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1624352/1990236).

> Next, what kind of code can/should I use to get that value from the
>   user and add it to the database?

You can do that with:

```
[transaction setValue:@(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) forKey:@"wasBought"];
```

You might also want to read about [subclassing `NSManagedObject`'s (section "Custom Managed Object Classes")](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003397-235678).

Comment: Thank you very much Arkadiusz, I will certainly look into the Enums and subclassing (I knew I wanted to get onto that eventually - just wanted to build the basis of the app but thanks for pointing me to that documentation as well) and the wasBought is a great idea. I will jump onto this now and write in with any further issues.. thanks again!