# Best way to implement Enums with Core Data in Swift

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, swift, enums

Very similar question to [Best way to implement Enums with Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624297/best-way-to-implement-enums-with-core-data)

What is the best way to bind Core Data entities to enum values so that I am able to assign a type property to the entity? In other words, I have an entity called Item with an itemType property that I want to be bound to an enum, what is the best way of going about this **in Swift**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to implement Enums with Core Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624297/best-way-to-implement-enums-with-core-data)

Comment: You do if the same way as any of those suggestions. It's not really good gorm to just ask people to translate objc code to Swift for you.

Comment: Abizern, see my first answer. No, this is not a duplicate question. The ObjC solutions cannot easily translated. Please review.

Answer (score 0):

So far, this is my best approach. I still use the ObjC enum definition, as suggested in Daniel Eggert's answer to the same ObjC question as the Swift Enum doesn't seem to be backward compatible to ObjC. 
Hence, I added it to my bridge header.